# showing bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle: No such file or directory in terminal

Tags: java, linux, bash, jvm

Whenever I open my terminal in my Kubuntu machine, I am getting the following shown on top: `bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle: No such file or directory`

This is happening ever since I added the line: `$JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle` in my .bashrc file. Can someone please tell me how to debug what is the problem, and if possible, a possible fix for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
JAVA_HOME=etc...
```

by doing

```
$JAVA_HOME=...
```

you're expanding the CURRENT value of the `JAVA_HOME` env var, and end up doing

```
oldvalue=newvalue
```

instead of "assign new value to var" that the `$`-less version does.

Answer (score 2):

While talking about variables on shell/bash, when we define a variable we **do not** use `$`, however, while accessing it, we need to use it with `$` symbol. For example,

1. Paste the line below, in your ~/.bashrc file.
       `JAVA_HOME = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`  (You just defined a variable)
2. Execute the command `source ~/.bashrc`
3. Execute: `echo $JAVA_HOME` (Here you're accessing the defined variable)

You will observe that value will be printed on the shell.